# if i create an object in destructor, what will happen?

Tags: c++, destructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class teacher{
private:
    int Tnum;
public:

    teacher(){
        Tnum = 0;
    }
    teacher(int n){
        cout << "creating teacher"<<endl;
        Tnum = n;
    }
    ~teacher(){
        cout << "destroying teacher" << endl;

    }   
};

class student: public teacher{

private:
    int Snum;

public:
    student(){
        Snum =0;
    }

    student(int n){
        cout << " creating student"<<endl;
        Snum = n;
    }
    ~student(){
        cout << "destroying student"<<endl;
       teacher t(1);
      cout << "teacher created"<<endl;
    }
};

int main(){

    teacher t(20);
    student s(30);

}
```

Comment: C++ allows you doing it, but it doesn't make any sense at all. What would you like to do this?

Comment: Well, it can make sense. You might create an instance of a class that, for examples, writes changes out to a database. Of course, you have the problem that the creation of an object can potentially throw an exception, and *destructors should never throw*.

Answer (score 3):

You showed an example that compiles. What happens?
It behaves just like an object created in any other function, and it will be destroyed once it goes out of scope.

From [12.4p8](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.dtor#8) we find that:

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body [...]

This confirms that creating objects in the body of the destructor is legal.

But, be careful! It could hurt you if the constructors of those objects throw exceptions, because destructors are non-throwing and encountering an exception would result in the termination of the application.

Comment: It is worth explicitly stating that a destructor is just a function which is automatically called when the object is destroyed. Other than the lack of return type and the `noexcept`, it is just a function.

Comment: Well, more or less. It belongs to the [special member functions](http://eel.is/c++draft/#special) section of the standard. Anyway, I got what you meant.